# JavaScript button manipulation according to Time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing an app and what i want is when the user clicks any button, this button will be hidden and only shows up after 24 hours. Here's what i've done so far.

```
<div class="buttons">
    <p><button onclick="hide();" type="button" name="button" id="button-he">Validar</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="hide();" type="button" name="button" id="button-hse">Validar</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="hide();" type="button" name="button" id="button-hre">Validar</button></p>
  </div>

  <script>
      function intervalo(){
        var but = document.getElementByTagName("button");
        but.style.visibility='hidden';
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: so you want a way to check wether or not 24hours has passed?

Comment: I hope you understand that with out server side and using setTimeout this will work only until the uer closes the page. Refreshing the page will reset setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is creating a cookie on the button click, that will last for 24 hours, and then check if the button should be clickable. Limitations of this approach will be if the user clears the cookies, the button will then again become clickable.

Take a look at this w3schools example: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

if you want to make sure that the user cant click the button again within 24 hours, you neeed to save this click event server side.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the PHP setcookie function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout( YOUR_FUNCTION, TIME_TO_WAIT )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and
>   successor to window.setTimeout) sets a timer which executes a function
>   or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.
>
> The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should
>   wait before the specified function or code is executed. If this
>   parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute
>   "immediately"

The method takes time in milliseconds so, you need convert your time to milliseconds.

For `24hr` you need to pass `24*60*60*1000` as a parameter.

**SNIPPET**

```js
function hide(but) {
  but.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  setTimeout(function(btn) {
    but.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }.bind(this, but), 1000); // Show after 1 second.
  // change 1000 to time you want 24*60*60*1000
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <p><button onclick="hide(this);" type="button" name="button" id="button-he">Validar</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="hide(this);" type="button" name="button" id="button-hse">Validar</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="hide(this);" type="button" name="button" id="button-hre">Validar</button></p>
</div>
```

The method will forget the timer if user refreshes the page.

If you want it to be persistent then you can store the `timestamp` when user clicks the button into `localstorage` and check if that time exceeded 24hrs on load of page.

Check this fiddle for [Implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/sypxrd0d/2/)

```
buttons = ["button-he", "button-hse", "button-hre"];
timer = 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000;
function init () {
  buttons.forEach(function(val) {
    var start = localStorage.getItem(val + '-timer');
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var but = document.getElementById(val);
    if (start && (end - start < timer)) {
        but.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        setTimeout(function(btn) {
        but.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }.bind(this, but), end-start);
    }
  })
}

init();

window.hide = function(but) {
  localStorage.setItem(but.id + '-timer', new Date().getTime());
  but.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  setTimeout(function(btn) {
    but.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }.bind(this, but), 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000); // Show after 1 second.
  // change 1000 to time you want 24*60*60*1000
}
```

Although, I suggest also check at the server side for this logic.

For that just pass the time-stamp when user clicks the button to the server and store it and check for time lapse.

Comment: The code is working, but when i refresh the page the button shows up. I want it to be enabled only when it's passed 24 hours.

Comment: Wait i am adding a fiddle to handle the case

Comment: Thank you for your help, you've helped me a lot @NadirLaskar